# How to use "Streaming-media" component

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm trying to use the "streaming-media" component to add to my Ionic application the ability to view live video.

I tried to use the example given on the component documentation, without success

```
let options: StreamingVideoOptions = {
  successCallback: () => { console.log('Video played') },
  errorCallback: (e) => { console.log('Error streaming') },
  orientation: 'landscape',
  shouldAutoClose: true,
  controls: false
};

this.streamingMedia.playVideo('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xC2s4HAWoXA', options);
```

I'm supposed to get the playback of the youtube video, but the video doesn't start.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.streamingMedia.playVideo('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xC2s4HAWoXA', options);
```

In here, you should use directly .mp4 etc file, instead of youtube video url.

For instance;

```
 this.streamingMedia.playVideo('https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/480/big_buck_bunny_480p_10mb.mp4', options);
```

Additionally, you should add ;

```
import {StreamingMedia,StreamingAudioOptions} from "@ionic-native/streaming-media/ngx";
```

to your page's .ts file and add StreamingMedia to app.module.ts 's providers section. Like that ;

```
  providers: [
StatusBar,
SplashScreen,
{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
StreamingMedia
   ]
```